# Which is the best way/pratice to work this scenario? Have I to use session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, authorization

*(Anyone can help me with a best title for this question? I try to think... but I don't have any success with best one than that.)*

Let me explain my following scenario and doubt.

I'm creating a website that will manage a lot of projects per user. Each user can be a owner or a participant only.

I have common areas for logged users, areas that all users from a project can access, and areas that only the owner can access.

I create a OwnerAuthorize attribute and a SimpleAuthorize attribute to Controllers and Actions:

```
public class OwnerAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var projectId = int.Parse(httpContext.Request.Params.Get("projectId"));
        var userId = httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
        project currentProject = null;

        using (var projectService = new ProjectsService())
        {
            currentProject = projectService.Find(projectId).Result;
        }

        if (currentProject == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentProject.OwnerId == userId)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SimpleAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var projectId = int.Parse(httpContext.Request.Params.Get("projectId"));
        var userId = httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
        Project currentProject = null;

        using (var projectService = new ProjectsService())
        {
            currentProject = projectService.Find(projectId).Result;
        }

        if (currentProject == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentProject.OwnerId == userId 
                || currentProject.Users.Select(u => u.Id).Contains(userId))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For few users, it's ok. But for many users, I have a database query to gather the same information for each action called. So, I was thinking to use a session to keep some informations of the current user and project accessed.

Which is the best way/pratice to work with this scenario?